# Is there a way to control app icon shortcut badge count in a react-native android application?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, badge

Actually the thing I want to achieve is, normally the shortcut icon badge count in android got cleared once the push notification popup is acknowledged by an user from notification panel, but instead clearing the count as above it has to be cleared only after the corresponding notification is acknowledged by an user within the app(for eg: if an user received a text message then the badge count will increased to one and once the user cleared the push notification popup form notification panel then the badge will also got cleared, but instead of that badge should be cleared only after the user viewed the message).

I tried the following packages.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-badge
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-badge

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use `ShortcutBadge.setCount(0);` to clear the badge counter!

I dont know what you use to display a notification on the android device itself, probably [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).

If that's the case, they also have a function for it:

`PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0)`

You just need to run one of these functions when the event of a dismissed notification triggers, which may or may not need some java coding for achieve it!

Comment: PushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0) this method only works for IOS, I want to customize badge count in android platform.

Comment: It says "Uses the ShortcutBadger on Android, and as such will not work on all Android devices." right under. It supports the following Android Launchers: Sony, Samsung, LG, HTC, Xiaomi, ASUS, ADW, APEX, NOVA, Huawei, ZUK, OPPO, EverythingMe, ZTE, KISS, LaunchTime, Yandex Launcher.